# Src jar for Pentaho Kettle

Tags: java, jar, pentaho, kettle

Where can I find a src-jar for Kettle? I'm looking for a jar that contains the Java files, and I can point my IDE to (like for example junit-4.6-src.jar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download source zip files from the [project web site](http://kettle.pentaho.org/). Then you just need to repackage it into a jar file.

It's pretty easy, in fact:

```
jar cvf src.jar -C src .
jar uvf src.jar -C src-core .
jar uvf src.jar -C src-db .
jar uvf src.jar -C src-ui .
```

(Doing it all in one go fails due to duplicate entries.)

Comment: At first I missed the fact lines 2-4 have 'uvf' instead of 'cvf' :)